# I am working on a project and I am newbie regarding cryptoanalysis using XOR. How can i use cryptoanalysis to get the plaintext?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, xor, brute-force

This may be really easy for some people. I do not quite understand how the XOR encrypted file can be broken using crytoanalysis and brute force. I have a PDF file that was encrypted using a program that XORed eight bytes by eight bytes. The code of program is

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

if (argc!=3) {
  printf("command (for example) : ./enc1 file_to_encrypt key_in_hex\n");
  return 1;
}

// get the key
unsigned long long key=strtoull(argv[2], NULL, 16);

// open the file
char* file=argv[1];
int fdp=open(file, O_RDONLY);
if (fdp<0) {
   printf("cannot open the file %s\n", file);
   return 1;
} 

 // open the file to save the encryption
 char enc[strlen(file)+10];
 strncpy(enc, file, strlen(file));
 strncpy(enc+strlen(file), ".enc1\0", 5);
 enc[strlen(file)+5]='\0';
 int fdc=open(enc, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);

 if (fdc<0) {
    printf("cannot save the encrypted file %s\n", enc);
    return 1;
}

  // encryption
  unsigned long long buf;
  unsigned long long k;
  int len;
  k=key;
  while ((len=read(fdp, (char*)&buf, 8))>0) {
  buf^=k;
  k*=key;
   write(fdc, (char*)&buf, len);
 }

 close(fdp);
 close(fdc);
 return 0;
}
```

I know that the headers of a PDF file are

%PDF-1.0
%PDF-1.1

How can I use that information to get the plaintext? Do I Xored the headers ?
Thanks very much

Comment: Bruteforce the keyspace until you can match those headers?

Answer (score 1):

XOR is easily reversible. Assume m is your original file and e its encrypted version. Then

```
e[0] = k[0] ^ m[0]
e[1] = k[1] ^ m[1]
e[2] = k[2] ^ m[2]
e[3] = k[3] ^ m[3]
```

But XOR is reversible, so you can find k by knowing part of e and m:

```
k[0] = e[0] ^ m[0]
k[1] = e[1] ^ m[1]
k[2] = e[2] ^ m[2]
k[3] = e[3] ^ m[3]
```

Comment: If i only have the encrypted file and the code that generated?

Comment: Almost all files have a magic number at offset 0. You can brute-force against known magic numbers and see whether the obtained key properly decrypts the file. E.g., you try m="%PDF", obtain a "k" and check whether the thus decrypted file is a valid PDF. Then you try with m="<?xml", m="JPEG", etc.

Comment: thanks for that. In the case of "magic numbers" the magic number of this pdf files would be: %pdf-1.0 %pdf-1.1 ... ? thanks a lot

Comment: Exactly. You try %pdf-1.0 first, if you obtain a valid PDF you're done. Otherwise, try %pdf-1.1.

Comment: @user120.. Thanks so much for the advice given. I am sorry but I have a question. The file I have encypher is a.pdf.enc1 which was encypher Xored with the code i posted before. the first 8 characters are     ,ë`^Eóýt¦[                                    Question? do i need to XORed this line with the next line in order to get the Key, seeing that whole file is made 8 by 8 bytes?

Comment: Oh i meant XOR the hex of the %PDF-1.N with the first 8 bytes encrypted??? and i guess keep going until i get the key???

Comment: Yes, exactly. I assume your file starts with "2c c3 ab 60 5e 45 c3 b3" (UTF-8 encoding of ",ë`^Eóýt¦["). %PDF-1.0 is "25 50 44 46 2d 31 2e 30" in hex. XORing the two gives: "09 93 ef 26 73 74 ed 83". Otherwise, testing with %PDF-1.1 gives "09 93 ef 26 73 74 ed 82". What was the original encryption key?

Answer (score 1):

The OP hasn't accepted an answer, and still seems to have questions, so here's my answer drawing on those by user1202136 and OmnipotentEntity.

To determine the key, XOR character by character the first 8 characters of the encrypted file with the header string you expect it to be, such as %PDF-1.4. The result is a same-length string which you can copy into an `unsigned long long` for the key (which also occupies 8 bytes.) Your program expects a hexadecimal key value, because `strtoull` is given a basis parameter of 16. Therefore use the `%llx` specifier to format the result, otherwise it'll be decimal and won't work.

```
void find_key(const char *filename, const char *m)
{
    // open the encrypted file
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!fp)
        return;

    // read encrypted header
    char e[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        e[i] = fgetc(fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // xor with known header
    char k[8];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        k[j] = e[j] ^ m[j];

    // copy into 8 byte value, and output in base-16
    unsigned long long newkey;
    memcpy(&newkey, &k, 8);
    printf("Testing for %s gives key %llx\n", m, newkey);
}
```

As you're not sure of the header version run it a few times with different options. If the encrypted file was one of these .pdf versions, then you'll have a key with which to decrypt it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        return 1;
    find_key(argv[1], "%PDF-1.0");
    find_key(argv[1], "%PDF-1.1");
    find_key(argv[1], "%PDF-1.2");
    find_key(argv[1], "%PDF-1.3");
    find_key(argv[1], "%PDF-1.4");
    return 0;
}
```

Your program is used for both encryption and decryption. This is because of the reversible nature of XOR as answered above. Pass the encrypted filename and the generated key as parameters.

In this test example, I first encrypt a .pdf using your program with a given key, then I find the key again with the above method, then I decrypt it with your program using the best key result.

```
$ ./enc1 test.pdf 1234ABCD
$ ./find-key test.pdf.enc1 
Testing for %PDF-1.0 gives key 30000001234abcd
Testing for %PDF-1.1 gives key 20000001234abcd
Testing for %PDF-1.2 gives key 10000001234abcd
Testing for %PDF-1.3 gives key 1234abcd
Testing for %PDF-1.4 gives key 70000001234abcd
$ ./enc1 test.pdf.enc1 1234abcd
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto user1202136's answer,

If you have two different messages encoded with the same key, you can retrieve the first `n` characters of the key (and both messages) (where `n` is the length of the shorter message) (this is how WEP cracking works, kids.)  (The following isn't code, but math.)

```
eA[0] = k[0] ^ mA[0]
eB[0] = k[0] ^ mB[0]
eA[0] ^ eB[0] = k[0] ^ k[0] ^ mA[0] ^ mB[0]
eA[0] ^ eB[0] = mA[0] ^ mB[0]
eA[0] ^ eB[0] ^ mA[0] = mB[0]
mB[0] ^ eB[0] = k[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for that information. When you say messages, you mean I have to open the encrypted file and grab two lines?

Comment: eA is the first encoded message, mA is the first plaintext message, k is the key.  XOR encryption is applied bitwise in parallel, meaning that each piece of the encryption is applied independently from any other.  For your particular question, you don't seem to have two messages encoded with the same key.  Because you know that the encoding is 8x8 you can still recover part of the key as detailed in user1202136's answer.